# Evitar que EditText se expanda con texto largo

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un `EditText` y dos botones en un relative layout. El problema es que al escribir un texto demasiado largo en el `EditText`, aunque cabe, el texto se muestra detrás de los botones. Me gustaría saber si se puede limitar hasta donde se expande, ponerle un tamaño fijo y hacer que se pueda meter el mismo texto aunque no se vea todo lo escrito (con un funcionamiento similar a la barra de un navegador en la que se escribe la URL).

Este es mi código respecto a estos tres elementos que, como he dicho, se encuentran en un mismo `RelativeLayoout`

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/IH"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:inputType=""
                android:text="@string/texto3"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/guardar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText17"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText17"
                android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/bot1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/borrar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/guardar"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guardar"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/guardar"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/guardar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/guardar"
                android:text="@string/bot2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Comment: no puedes poner un `LinearLayout(Horizontal)` y a los 3 pasarles la propiedad `match_parent` para resolver tu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de solucionar tu problema es el siguiente:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Si te preguntas el porqué puse un `LinearLayout` para contener esos 3 elementos, la respuesta es fácil, si utilizas `LinearLayout`, puedes asignarle a los 3 elementos la propiedad `match_parent` y se deben acomodar, debes recordar que la propiedad `wrap_content` **se ajusta al tamaño del componente**, así que, si el contenido del componente crece, crecerá con él. 
Si por alguna razón, cuando le pongas la propiedad `match_parent` no se acomoda, puedes seleccionar los 3 desde el editor y utilizar la siguiente opción:
[image: opción]